# Installing node-sass on ubuntu 18.04 returns error

Tags: node.js, linux, sass, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install node-sass on ubuntu, beacuse I want to use sass-autocompile, but even when I try to compile that sass file in atom (just when I save it)
It returns this error:

```
`fs.js:904
   return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding) 

 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 
   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
   at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
   at Object.getInstalledBinaries (/usr/lib/node_modules/node- 
     sass/lib/extensions.js:129:13)
   at foundBinariesList (/usr/lib/node_modules/node- 
     sass/lib/errors.js:20:15)
   at foundBinaries (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:15:5)
   at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (/usr/lib/node_modules/node- 
     sass/lib/errors.js:45:5)
   at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:30)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node- 
      sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
   at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:565:32)`
```

I tried to use this command `npm rebuild node-sass` and it didn't fix the problem, even with `--force`

And removing nodejs and node-sass and npm and installing again didn't fix the problem and yes I do have ruby installed.

But one thing is really strange: this path `node_modules/node-sass/vendor'` exists in home folder, basically `node_modules` exists in home folder even with that vendor folder. Can you help me out ?

[image: Home directory]

[image: usr directory]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution which works for me

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Update: Since node-sass is mostly deprecated use instead sass npm module(works perfect whithout any issues).You can find it [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass).

Answer (score 2):

so after reading some of the workarounds on https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1579 here is my suggestion

first remove `node_modules` directory and re-install dependencies `npm install` if its still not working then

```
node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js

npm rebuild node-sass
```

if it's still not working, change your `node-sass` version to the latest and re-install it again

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't work. I have no idead why it is not working. I'll try reinstalling whole system and delete everything and try it again.

Comment: But is it right that node_modules is in home folder ??

Comment: what do you mean by  is it right that node_modules is in home folder?

Comment: whats your node and npm version? do you use nvm?

Comment: I have two node_modules folders in total. One is in /usr/lib/ and second one is in /home as you can see on that 2 pictures I posted.